# Cppcheck GUI: Excluding a file or folder from checking

Tags: configuration-files, static-analysis, cppcheck

I am using Cppcheck GUI to scan my projects (new in Cppcheck, just starded to use it) and want to exclude some sub folders when I am scanning my project.

How to exclude some sub folder when scanning project folder with cppcheck GUI?

I have watched some videos on YouTube and tried to exclude as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_-MT1oXgNM) but it still scanning excluded sub folders.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's even possible to [do so in the project file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46033602/2932052)

Answer (score 6):

Excluding a file or folder from checking
To exclude a file or folder, there are two options. The first option is to only provide the paths and files
you want to check.

```
cppcheck src/a src/b
```

All files under src/a and src/b are then checked.
The second option is to use -i, with it you specify files/paths to ignore. With this command no files in
src/c are checked:

```
cppcheck -isrc/c src
```

ref : http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf

Answer (score 5):

As of version 1.80, [the manual](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf) still misses to describe the structure of GUI project files (chapter 12). The GUI itself has a lot of flaws, so I consider editing the project file through the GUI a waste of time. On the other hand, having these project files (under version control) and editing them by hand proved to be useful.

Here is the structure of a minimal project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="1"/>
```

With such a file, Cppcheck is run on all potential C/C++ source files in the directory the cppcheck project file resides in (recursively including subfolders). You may **exclude files or paths** like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="1">
    <exclude>
        <path name="utilities/fileToExclude.c"/>
        <path name="utilities/pathToExclude/"/>
    </exclude>
</project>
```

***Note:*** If you have the project already open in the GUI and edited its project file, remember to re-open the project file, only re-running all checks will not force a refresh of the project settings.

Comment: There is some documentation in a [textfile in the source repository](https://trac.cppcheck.net/browser/gui/projectfile.txt?rev=4b67780baecce274e83efe8d7bd49cf2b2b1d5e9).

Answer (score 3):

As of cppcheck-gui 1.88, the option to add excluded paths is found on the "Warning Options" tab:

[image: screen grab of warning options tab]